# Are there any benefits to keep your files (scripts) on WSL filesystem

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When reading the WSL documentation, it is stated that:

*"Unlike our practice with trying to exclusively install programs and software on Ubuntu, our files and folders need to live exclusively on the Windows FS [...] Windows and Windows Apps can only read and write Windows files, and VSCode will be making our changes."*

I understand the reasoning behind this and indeed, if one uses VSCode for example, it all makes sense. But my question is:

**Is there any real reason why you couldn't keep your files (i.e. scripts) on the WSL filesystem itself? More specifically, if you don't ever intend to use the Windows filesystem (i.e you won't ever need a GUI or else), is there any sense in placing the files in the Windows FS?**

Obviously you need to make sure you backup your data (GitHub or else) but aside from that, is there any downside? I guess what I'm saying is: can I use WSL like a VM? Can I keep BOTH software AND scripts all in WSL, separate from the Windows filesystem?

PS: The reason for avoiding a VM in this context is because I have a low spec laptop which has struggled a lot in the past with VMs (slow, not enough RAM), and so far, WSL seems be running much more smoothly.

Thanks

Comment: There is a filesystem explicitly for WSL, and it can store files. Obviously, you may store the files there. So, what is a **problem**? If you want to get **all** pros and cons, then Stack Overflow is a bad place for such questions. Moreover, Stack Overflow is for **programming** questions, but your one is of other sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and only place files in the Windows filesystem if you want to share them with Windows programs. Moreover, in Windows 1903 you don't need to place files in Windows filesystem to share them with Windows Programs, they can access them.

In WSL2 they encourage you to keep everything in WSL filesystem to take advantage of the filesystem's performance improve.

So, yes you can and you should.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, you can use WSL as if it were a VM. WSL is for the most part fully-fledged Linux, and you can use Linux as your primary operating system, ignoring the fact you need to start it from within Windows. I haven't tried WSL 2, but it's said to be implemented as a [fast VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-ux-changes#wsl-2-will-use-some-memory-on-startup), which is exactly what you ask for. (Further, the lack of GUIs can be mitigated using built in support for sending [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) data over SSH to the Windows half of your computer, and display it with an X Server. If I remember correctly, these [two](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-a-pretty-and-usable-terminal-emulator-for-wsl/) [articles](https://medium.com/@bhupathy/install-terminator-on-windows-with-wsl-2826591d2156) got me most of my way there.)

However, if you want to get pedantic, you can't store any files separate from your Windows filesystem on WSL 1. If you run e.g. Ubuntu, your Linux filesystem is instead always *contained within* `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState`, so it'll technically not be separate. I can't test WSL 2, but according to [this article](https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux/#sharing-file-systems), WSL 2 also stores its data in that folder, just as a single VDHX image. Presumably every WSL distro stores its data on the Windows filesystem.

Warning: Do not access the files themselves in your Linux filesystem within AppData using Windows tools, or you run a [high risk of corrupting those files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).